# How to get selected option from selected componets in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```js
<div class="fligtInput flex flex-no-wrap">
    <SelectFlight
        v-model="flight.model1" placeholder="from"
    ></SelectFlight>

    <SelectFlight
        v-model="flight.model2" placeholder="to"
    ></SelectFlight>
</div>
```

I use (select option) SelectFlight Component and this returns a JSON object. I wanna take the selected options for both components in parent component.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show how you are implementing the `<SelectFlight />` component in the parent as well as the data structure the v-model is binding too? Also you mentioned that both of the `<SelectFlight />` are returning json objects? Are you looking to merge the too objects? Sample data from the returned object would be helpful.

Comment: SelectFlight is a component and i use this componnet two times in a parent component. I ahve a json onject in SelectFlight component. İt shows some airports . And when i choose airports i want to show them in parent element. ``` data() {
    return {
      model: "",
      loading1: false,
      options1: [],
      list: citynames,
    
    };
  },```

Comment: You can either use a computed property which can be called from the parent, or you can emit an event with the selected items which event should be handled by the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a stab at an example showing multiple options, knowing I don't have the full context of your specific problem, but I am sure this example will get you pointed in the right direction.

I took liberty with object names, and assumed values in JSON objects. Obviously you will ned to adjust this for your specific use case and data.

```
<template>
  <div class="i-am-the-parent">
    <!-- 
      Display flight from name
     -->
    <div
      v-if="flights.from"
      class="display-text-from"
    >
      {{ flights.from.airportName }}
    </div>
    <SelectFlight
      v-model="flights.from"
      placeholder="from"
    />

    <!-- Bind flight to "airportName" as a prop in parent -->
    <ParentWrapperComponent
      class="display-text-to"
      :airport-name="flights.to ? flights.to.airportName : null"
    >
      <!--
        Nested in ParentWrapperComponent
      -->
      <SelectFlight
        v-model="flights.to"
        placeholder="to"
      />
    </ParentWrapperComponent>

    <!--
      Kitchen Sink
      Here I am demonstrating multiple approaches:
      1. Merge the data via a computed property and pass as a property named airports
      2. Simply pass the flights data property as a flights property
      3. Simply pass the properties "flights.from" data as property "from" and "flights.to" data as property "to"
    -->
    <SomeComponentToShowBoth
      :airports="combineValues"
      :flights="flights"
      :from="flights.from"
      :to="flights.to"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SelectFlight from '@/path/to/component/SelectFlight'
export default {
  components: {
    SelectFlight
  },
  data () {
    return {
      flights: {
        from: null,
        to: null
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    combineValues () {
      // this will return both json objects merged into one.
      // It will update everytime this.flights.from or this.flights.to changes
      return Object.assign({}, this.flights.from, this.flights.to)
    },
    combineFlightNames () {
      // Perhaps you just want to pass the names?
      return {
        from: flights.from ? flights.from.airportName : null,
        to: flights.to ? flights.to.airportName : null
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

References:

- [Vue Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)
- [Vue Component Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)
- [Vue Reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)